# go large memory garbage collection performance

Tags: go

I am considering implementing a memory caching daemon in Go.  It has potential of getting some serious memory utilization (say, Terabyte).  Fragmenting into separate heaps is not a good option, I want it all in one memory space.  Does anyone have experience running Go with such huge memory sizes?  Is GC going to perform acceptably?

Comment: Given the requirements you list, I would be very tempted to write such a program in a non-GCed language. Good cache expiry is hard enough without worrying about GC as well.

Comment: Also, if your needs are simple you may not have to implement anything yourself; groupcache (https://github.com/golang/groupcache) may do just what you need.

Comment: @Evan I thought about groupcache; I'm pretty sure it is not what I need because I plan to put quite a bit of processing logic into my "cache" (such as aggregation).  Problem is, there are not many non-GC'ed languages I can force myself to use.  The thought of doing this in C++ terrifies me.

Comment: If it's a terabyte of largeish blocks, then you might choose to use mmap for the raw data and garbage collection only for the metadata. That's basically what groupcache does. If you are going to have a terabyte of 16-byte blocks, that's a different story.

Comment: @RussCox I'm thinking relatively large blocks (say, thousands for 10Mb chunks).  mmap sounds interesting, but I don't see any references to mmap usage in https://github.com/golang/groupcache ?

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to do the same but the only projects that gave me a good performance to cache data was the binary tree https://github.com/stathat/treap m which supported more than 1 millons of nodes on memory in one machine Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS with 8 GB memory. Furthermore,  it was fast loading and searching data.

Other projects that I tested was [LMDB](http://symas.com/mdb/) but not support many nodes on memory, [kv](http://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/kv), [go-cache](https://github.com/robfig/go-cache) and [goleveldb](https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb) but no one was as faster to recovery data from memory that treap.